# Trying to replace this block-based NSSortDescriptor with a Core Data-friendly one

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I've got an entity type which, as one of its properties, has a single character.  I want to retrieve all such entities which match a predicate, and I want them to be sorted first by that character, and then by an index number (which is another of its properties).

This is simple if I just use the built-in sort descriptors... however, the single character can be anything from a letter to a number to punctuation to an emoji.  And when I use the built-in sort, I get punctuation first, then numbers, and then so on.  What I want is A-Z first, then numbers, then punctuation, then finally emoji or other non-alphanumeric-and-non-punctuation (those last ones I don't really care about their order).

This is easy enough to implement as a block-based NSSortDescriptor, but I can't figure out how to do it in a way that I can send it off to Core Data as part of a fetch request (i.e., no blocks allowed).  I'd be fine with breaking it into a couple different requests, if that's the only way to do it, and then joining the resulting arrays afterward; but I'd prefer to do it in one fetch if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the objects in the first place, run your sort logic and save a resulting 'characterType' into another property. Now, on your fetch request, use 3 sort descriptors, with this character type identifier first, then the character and then the other index.

Comment: This won't quite work in my situation because it would require re-sorting every time an entity was added or modified... However, it would work in many cases, and it also gives me an idea of adding not an index per se, but just a broader "character type" numeric field, with 1 for a letter, 2 for a number, 3 for punctuation/other.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by 'index', but your naming is better :-)